# How to amend a pre-existing .db file by creating an SQLite table using git bash

Tags: php, git, bash, sqlite

I am having difficulty using SQLite in Git Bash to create a table in a database file.

I am following the book Jump Start PHP Environment by Bruno Skvorc.

I have used vagrant to set up a homestead_improved virtual box, and changed directory to the root of my project, run vagrant ssh to log in to the box and then run:

```
     sqlite3 storage/database.db
```

The terminal responds with:

```
     SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
```

and the prompt sqlite> so it appears that I have SQLite version 3. however when I try to create a table with the following command:

```
    CREATE TABLE comments (
    ...> id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    ...> name TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...> email TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...> comment TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...> submissionDate TEXT NOT NULL
    ...> );
```

I receive the following response:
Error: unable to open database "storage/database.db": unable to opendatabase file

It also appears that I am kicked out of SQLite as the prompt reverts back to vagrant@homestead:~1

I have tried various options like simply opening SQLite and then opening the database file. I have tried various 'addresses' including V:/hi_guestbook/guestbook/storage/database.db, both with and without a backslash preceding each forward slash.

Various people seem to suggest that SQLite creates a lock file in the location of the database.db file when it is opened, and that there are problems with windows but none of it seems to resolve the problem.

Can you help?

Comment: Does the `storage` directoy exists?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Yes both the storage directory and the database.db file exist. I think the answer relies on changing the write permissions in the storage directory but I am not sure quite how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

it happened with me today and i solved it..it came to me by intuition..somehow...weird.

ERROR:
`vagrant@homestead:~$ sqlite3 storage/database.db
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from comments;
Error: unable to open database "storage/database.db": unable to open database file`

Then i just went to `vagrant@homestead:~$ cd Code`

Then`vagrant@homestead:~/Code$ cd guestbook/`

and then `vagrant@homestead:~/Code/guestobook$ composer dump-autoload -o`

OUTPUT : `Generated optimized autoload files containing 101 classes` (`namespace` `classes` you created in your `comments.php` named file maybe ?)

Then i did `vagrant@homestead:~/Code/guestbook$ sqlite3 storage/database.db`
OUTPUT :->
`SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>`

Then i did `sqlite> select * from comments;` OUTPUT :->
`1|dfs sdff|1122@34234.ret|dfsdf dsf sdfs dfssdf fdsf sdfsd sdf sdfsdf sdfsdf !|2019-04-24 06:52:40
2|cxvcxvcxv|cvxcvx@dfgdfgd.com|sadsa asd asda sdaf fsf ssdf sdfsdf |2019-04-24 07:16:05
3|sasads767|123@123.com|dsfsf fssdfs sdfsdfs dsdfs sdf|2019-04-24 07:16:34
4|dsfsdf|sdsd@1213.com|rtete rre ertert erter tet terterterert er er|2019-04-24 07:27:58
5|fghfghfghfgh|fgfgh@gfghfg.gfhg|fdgdfgdf fd gdfg fdg fg 678678 768 76867 86786787 64 63456 45645 hgfh fgh f|2019-04-24 07:38:07
6|hello|hello@hello.com|sdf sddsf sdf fsdfsdf ffsdff dsfsdfsdf sdfdfsfsd fsfsdf  f dfsd fsd fs fsf|2019-04-25 17:45:08
sqlite>`

Comment: please indent your code and provide minimal explanation